# Unable to get REST API response in real android device in Ionic

Tags: angular, typescript, cordova, ionic-framework

Everything working fines in web browser but not working in debug.apk while running in real device(Android).

I'm not getting any response from https server in real device but in browser i'm getting response and displaying data in ion-label.

For browser:

```
ionic serve --lab
```

For android debug apk:

```
ionic cordova build android
```

config.xml:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="io.ionic.starter" version="0.0.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
    <name>NABH</name>
    <description>An awesome Ionic/Cordova app.</description>
    <author email="hi@ionicframework" href="http://ionicframework.com/">Ionic Framework Team</author>
    <content src="index.html" />
    <allow-intent href="*" />
    <allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="tel:*" />
    <allow-intent href="sms:*" />
    <allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
    <allow-intent href="geo:*" />
    <allow-navigation href="*" />
    <access origin="*" />
    <allow-navigation href="http://*/*" />
    <allow-navigation href="https://*/*" />
    <allow-navigation href="data:*" />
    <preference name="ScrollEnabled" value="false" />
    <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="19" />
    <preference name="BackupWebStorage" value="none" />
    <preference name="SplashMaintainAspectRatio" value="true" />
    <preference name="FadeSplashScreenDuration" value="300" />
    <preference name="SplashShowOnlyFirstTime" value="false" />
    <preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen" />
    <preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="300" />
    <preference name="loadUrlTimeoutValue" value="600000" />
    <preference name="AutoHideSplashScreen" value="false" />
    <preference name="orientation" value="portrait" />
    <platform name="android">
        <allow-intent href="market:*" />
        <icon density="ldpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-ldpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="mdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-mdpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="hdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-hdpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="xhdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xhdpi-icon.png" />
.......
```

Followed some tutorial link and added below line also in `index.html` file,

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'">
```

ionic.config.json file:

```
{
  "name": "NXXX",
  "app_id": "",
  "type": "ionic-angular",
  "integrations": {
    "cordova": {}
  },
  "proxies": [
    {
      "path": "/api",
      "proxyUrl": "https://www.testapi.com/mobileapi"
    }
  ]

}
```

ts file:

```
return new Promise(resolve => {
      const myheader = new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded')
      this.http.get("https://www.testapi.com/mobileapi",{headers:myheader}).subscribe(data => {
        resolve(data);
      }, err => {
        console.log(err);
      });
    });
```

Environment info:
cli packages: (/usr/local/lib/node_modules)

```
@ionic/cli-utils  : 1.19.2
ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.20.0
```

global packages:

```
cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.0.0
```

local packages:

```
@ionic/app-scripts : 3.1.9
Cordova Platforms  : android 7.0.0
Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2
```

System:

```
Android SDK Tools : 26.1.1
Node              : v8.11.1
npm               : 5.6.0
OS                : macOS High Sierra
Xcode             : Xcode 7.2.1 Build version 7C1002
```

Still, i'm getting stuck at api response in real device. Please let me know what will i do to get JSON response in android device?

Answer (score 0):

It might be a CORS issue, you should check if CORS is activated in your backend.

If everything works fine in browser I see no other way.

Comment: How do i check CORS is activated or not in backend?

Comment: @pb123 is this backend yours?

Comment: For CORS issue, i have added proxyUrl in ionic.config.json file, such as ,
"proxies": [
    {
      "path": "/api",
      "proxyUrl": "https://example.com"
    }
  ]

Comment: @pb123 then you have to check in console what's going on, connect your phone to computer and inspect your application in Google Chrome https://ionic.zone/debug/remote-debug-your-app#android